# Implement Drag and Drop, vertical sorting on rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4, angularjs-directive

I have an HTML code which looks like this. I want to apply DRAG and DROP functionality on these rows (table-data).

```
<table>
   <tr class="table-header">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Modified By</th>
      <th>Date</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr class="table-data" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>item.title</td>
      <td>item.name</td>
      <td>item.modifiedByName</td>
      <td>item.modifiedDate</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In my ANGULAR JS controller my ITEMS array is of the below format

```
$scope.items = [
        {
           title: "string"
           name: "string"
           modifiedByName: "string"
           modifiedDate: "string"
           defaultOrder: 1
        },
        {
           title: "string"
           name: "string"
           modifiedByName: "string"
           modifiedDate: "string"
           defaultOrder: 2
        },
        {
           title: "string"
           name: "string"
           modifiedByName: "string"
           modifiedDate: "string"
           defaultOrder: 3
        },
        {
           title: "string"
           name: "string"
           modifiedByName: "string"
           modifiedDate: "string"
           defaultOrder: 4
        }
]
```

**Angular JS Version - 1.5.8**

- Need to display rows as per 'defaultOrder' parameter.
- Once the user updates his/her preference using drag and drop the default order should get updated and then sent to the server accordingly.

Comment: I would advise not to implement it by your own hands (unless you want to get the knowledge on how to do this). Take a look into something ready, like this
https://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/

Comment: i cant use these third party solutions as i mentioned that i need this solution for my website which is in production already. Also this isn't a licensed solution. Need help on creating a directive or maybe any solution that is Licensed under MIT

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is under MIT already https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: ohh yes. My Bad, but need a solution that doesn't use this library. Of u see the link you shared, it doesn't provide any warenty for the solution. Also support would be an issue, as it was last updated in 2013

Comment: Please take a look to this library, in the past I used it with success [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-legacy-sortablejs)

Comment: @aUXcoder thank you for the library, but then it would be really helpfull if you could help me with a working solution, also i want to save the order of the items once the items have been dragged and dropped. If you could post a small snippet it would be really great. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular JS Team has provided a directive (library) to achieve the above functionality.

Below is the github link.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable